# Can I define a method which take 1 or N string values as arguments

Tags: c#, .net

I'm pretty sure at some point I've read about this and I think it's possible (not very sure though) but I can not recall how to make it. I want to make a validation method which can take take as arguments 1 or many strings which should be validated against the same rules.
So basicly  what I need is something like this:

```
public bool CheckMyStringValues (Strings...)
{
//My common logic for all strings
}
```

And this will be in my base class, then call it from my child classes like :

```
CheckMyStringValues("firstString")
or
CheckMyStringValues("firstString", "secondSTring")
..
and so on...
```

Comment: you can define parameter as a type of param[] string

Comment: '1 or more' or any number of args?

Comment: At least 1, could be many (more than 1). Max 30.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
public bool CheckMyStringValues(params string[] strings)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) array:

```
public bool CheckMyStringValues (params string[] strings)
{
    foreach(string str in strings)
    {
        if(yourCondition)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can use it in several ways:

```
bool result = CheckMyStringValues(); // empty array
result = CheckMyStringValues(null);  // array is null
result = CheckMyStringValues("");    // one empty string in array
result = CheckMyStringValues("firstString"); // one string in array
result = CheckMyStringValues("firstString", "secondString"); // etc ...
result = CheckMyStringValues(new[]{"firstString", "secondString", "thirdString"});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool CheckMyStringValues (params string[] list)
{
}
```

This will allow you to invoke that method using `CheckMyStringValue("1stString", "2ndString")`